# CSS selection in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a page which contains:

```
    <td class="tablec" width="50%">
        <div class="atomic"><strong>Date:</strong> Tuesday, October 31, 2017 At 08:00</div>
        <div class="atomic"><strong>Duration:</strong> 1 day</div>
    </td>
```

Information that I need to retrieve is that `1 day`

Anyway, I do:

```
soup_cal = BeautifulSoup(page_cal.content, 'html.parser')
selected = soup_cal.select("td.tablec > div.atomic")
for lines in selected:
    print(lines.get_text())
```

but it is empty. Could you give some hint how to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `bs4`, the right way to extract text from a tag is using the `.text/.content/.string` properties.

```
for line in soup.select("td.tablec > div.atomic"):
     print(line.text)

Date: Tuesday, October 31, 2017 At 08:00
Duration: 1 day
```

If you only want the output from the last line, you'd use:

```
dur = soup.select("td.tablec > div.atomic")[-1].text.split(None, 1)[-1]

print(dur)
1 day
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But it still doesn't print anything. It seems that `soup.select("td.tablec > div.atomic")` returns nothing.

Comment: @bLAZ When I copy the snippet into my terminal, it runs fine. My guess is you're scraping from a site that dynamically loads content with JS.

Comment: @COLDSPEED hmm, is that a problem if it is loaded by JS? `print(soup_cal)` shows me the page source

Comment: @bLAZ yes, bs4 only scrapes static content. You'll need a webdriver for dynamic content. Look at `selenium`.

Comment: @COLDSPEED but with `soup_cal = BeautifulSoup(page_cal.content, 'html.parser')`I get content of that page.

Comment: @bLAZ Okay but is this specific content present? Did you see it? If you didn't, that means it was dynamically loaded. That's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Yes, I see it. It is nested in other tags. Full CSS Path is `html body div div table.maintable tbody tr td.tablec div.atomic`

Comment: @bLAZ Are you using bs3 or bs4? If you're using bs3, please switch to bs4.

Comment: @COLDSPEED It is bs4

Comment: @bLAZ It'd be helpful if you could provide the url. I can't debug your problem like this.

Comment: @COLDSPEED sorry for that. It is intranet page. I can share page source (replaced some 'sensitive info' with aaaaa): https://pastebin.com/vjsCNbAr

Comment: @COLDSPEED I had a typo in another css selector (in tag name) which is using the same `soup_cal` and it caused that following selection didn't work. At least from you I have learned how to use it properly. Thank you!